# Copying plain text from a WYSIWYG to a normal text area

Tags: html, textarea, wysiwyg

am having a WYSIWYG textarea which i would like to copy the text (as-plane) and insert it to another textarea on the same form as plane text using javascript..............HELP! :-)

Comment: Why do people only edit the title but leave the body a mess?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the innerHTML property. A sample code:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById('newArea').innerHTML = document.getElementById('oldArea').innerHTML;
</script>
```

Where "newArea" is the textarea to copy to and "oldArea" the textarea to copy from.

Comment: am new to these stuff so bare with my 'simple questions'....this i what i have....

function Change{
document.getElementById('textCopied').innerHTML = document.getElementById('welcomeEmail').innerHTML;
}
<? //this is where i called the function with the onclick event?>

<input name="copyText" type="button" value="Copy Text" onclick="Change();" />

Comment: This looks fine. What is the problem ?